# Очень медленно выполняется простейший SELECT запрос

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Есть простая таблица с двумя полями - `text` и `pathname`. В первом поле хранится текст (в среднем 2000 символов), а во втором - URL запрошенной страницы. При открытии страницы выполняется запрос к базе. Если найдена запись с нужным `pathname`, то функция возвращает текст этой записи. Почему-то этот запрос выполняется непозволительно долго на фоне остальных - 200 миллисекунд.

```
function getBottomPageText($request_uri) {
    $postgre = new Postgre();
    $connect = $postgre->connect();

    $query = "SELECT text FROM tickets_bottom_text WHERE pathname = '{$request_uri}'";
    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

    pg_close($connect);

    if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);

        return array(
            'text' => $row['text']
        );
    } else {
        return array(
            'text' => null
        );
    }
}
```

Почему так сильно проседает производительность при простейшей выборке текста? В таблице всего 10 записей.

Comment: Так `request_uri` или  `pathname`? И столбец по которому идет поиск индексирован?

Comment: @MaxU `pathname` - перепутал при написании. Что значит "индексирован"?

Comment: [Индекс (базы данных)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_(%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85))

Comment: функция уязвима к атаке SQL-injection :-))
параметр $request_uri нужно фильтровать
(https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: @DSKalugin функция вызывается на строго определённых страницах и ввести `example.com/;DROP TABLE ...` не выйдет. Но всё равно зафильтрую, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположу, что у вас отсутствует индекс по полю `request_uri`.

Создайте индекс (судя по вашему описанию он может быть уникальным) в вашей БД:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_tickets_bottom_text ON tickets_bottom_text(request_uri);
```

PS поиск по уникальному индексу обычно быстрее чем по неуникальному.

PPS даже несмотря на то, что у вас всего 10 записей в таблице - они занимают несколько [страниц](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/storage-page-layout.html) (хранится текст в среднем 2000 символов), если поле `request_uri` занимает значительно меньше памяти, то возможно весь индекс поместится в меньшее количество страниц. В любом случае при доступе при помощи уникального индекса понадобится чтение одной дополнительной страницы данных (если вернуть надо поле(я), не содержащееся в самом индексе).

Comment: Сработало. Запрос стал выполнятся за 0.012 секунд. Спасибо. А теперь при добавлении новых записей в таблицу она будет заново индексироваться?

Comment: Будет обновляться индекс только для новых записей - это достаточно быстрая операция

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, всегда рад помочь :)

Answer (score 0):

Поиск по строковым полям осуществляется медленнее чем поиск по полям типа `int`. Попробуйте указать поле pathname как индекс

Comment: Какая связь между `int` и индексом по строковому полю?

Comment: Вопрос ведь был не в этом, человек спрашивал почему поиск осуществляется медленно. Я незвал причины